# Loading associated data in a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

That's probably a terrible title, but here goes.

I have two models, Item and Category. It's a many-to-many relationship (items can belong to multiple categories, categories can hold multiple items).

What's the best way to look up (e.g. by 'name') list of categories and find all items included in them? If I were using SQL, I'd do something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE category_id in (
   SELECT id FROM category
   WHERE name IN ('cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3')
)
```

or something, but I'd like to do it in a Railsy way if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
Item.joins(:categories).where("categories.name" => ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

`Item.includes(:categories).where("categories.name IN(?)", list_of_names)`

Comment: No good - I'm starting with a list of "names", not the IDs. The IDs need looking up first - easy enough if we use two separate queries, but I'm hoping to do it with one.

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: category.name: SELECT "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE (category.name IN('music')) - the result from that code. Edit: changing includes to joins fixed it :) Thanks to you and user229688.